# change color of background when hover image

Tags: html, css

I need to change color when my image on hover.

I have div with img inside, so when I hover my image I change opacity to 0.3 but the color is white and I wanna change it to green,
is it possible??

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6" style="padding: 0px !important;width:50px;height: 350px">  
              <img class="img-fluid " id="myImg" src="img1.png" alt="" style="width:100%;height: 100%">
          </div>
#myImg{
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
#myImg:hover,{
  opacity: 0.3;}
```

[this is what I need to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AI1M1.png)

[this what I am able to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWBZx.png)

Comment: So set the background color? Does setting it to green not do what you want?

Comment: You must add an overlay `div` next to image, set its position to `absolute` and change its color and etc on hover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The white that you are seeing is from the background's white. Instead, what you probably want to do here is to change the opacity and color of the div rather than of the img like so:

**CSS**

```
.demo{
  background-color: green;
}

#myImg:hover{
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="demo col-md-4 col-sm-6" style="padding: 0px !important;width:50px;height: 350px">  
    <img class="img-fluid " id="myImg" src="https://picsum.photos/50/350" alt="" style="width:100%;height: 100%">
</div>
```

Comment: May be more change the `opacity` of the `img` and have the `background-color` of `div` green. I don't think we want the `opacity` to be apply on the `background-color`.

Comment: Yes, I realized that as I re-read my answer. I was making the edit as you commented this.